# React changes the SVG component color

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm importing an SVG component to my homepage but it changes the colors. 
Any suggestions why?

I exported the SVG from Figma and then I converted it to a react component. It seems that the structure is fine but react changing the linear gradient colors

**Here is how it should look**
[Optimal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTco0.png)

**And here is the result**
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzbjR.png)

**Here is the SVG component code:**

```
import React from 'react'
function Bg() {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      width='315'
      height='315'
      fill='none'
      viewBox='0 0 315 315'
    >
      <g filter='url(#filter0_d)'>
        <rect
          width='215'
          height='215'
          x='50'
          y='30'
          fill='url(#paint0_linear)'
          rx='20'
        ></rect>
      </g>
      <mask
        id='a'
        width='215'
        height='215'
        x='50'
        y='30'
        maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
      >
        <rect width='215' height='215' x='50' y='30' fill='#fff' rx='20'></rect>
      </mask>
      <g mask='url(#a)'>
        <path
          fill='url(#paint1_linear)'
          fillRule='evenodd'
          d='M-260.867 73.26s141.688-69.107 366.272-46.072C329.988 50.225 376.783-94 376.783-94h67.891v205.654l-19.616 79.854s-174.342 90.387-297.706 74.404C3.987 249.929-116.682 229.21-280.674 313.855-444.666 398.499-260.867 73.26-260.867 73.26z'
          clipRule='evenodd'
        ></path>
        <mask
          id='b'
          width='794'
          height='422'
          x='-349'
          y='-94'
          maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <path
            fill='#fff'
            fillRule='evenodd'
            d='M-260.867 73.26s141.688-69.107 366.272-46.072C329.988 50.225 376.783-94 376.783-94h67.891v205.654l-19.616 79.854s-174.342 90.387-297.706 74.404C3.987 249.929-116.682 229.21-280.674 313.855-444.666 398.499-260.867 73.26-260.867 73.26z'
            clipRule='evenodd'
          ></path>
        </mask>
        <g fillRule='evenodd' clipRule='evenodd' mask='url(#b)'>
          <path
            fill='url(#paint2_linear)'
            d='M206.244 49.455s-88.496 20.87-66.688 62.769c21.807 41.898-96.135 67.071-96.135 67.071s-191.295 48.959 152.243 77.397C539.202 285.13 266.668 32 266.668 32l-60.424 17.455z'
          ></path>
          <path
            fill='url(#paint3_linear)'
            d='M368.503 43.065s-88.497 20.87-66.689 62.769c21.808 41.899-96.135 67.072-96.135 67.072s-191.295 48.959 152.243 77.396C701.46 278.74 428.926 25.61 428.926 25.61l-60.423 17.455z'
          ></path>
          <path
            fill='url(#paint4_linear)'
            d='M77.956 20.083s39.354 109.215 91.587 78.156c52.233-31.06 125.784 0 125.784 0s117.847 57.011-20.222-131.536c-138.07-188.547-197.15 53.38-197.15 53.38z'
          ></path>
          <path
            fill='#fff'
            d='M-300.764 280.795s179.01-71.089 334.723 0C189.672 351.884 393.13 178.221 393.13 178.221S579.363 1.496 736.857 200.609C894.352 399.722 55.329 443.997 55.329 443.997l-390.215-67.972 34.122-95.23z'
            opacity='0.45'
          ></path>
          <path
            fill='#fff'
            d='M-278.479 225.622s181.385-64.804 334.52 11.671c153.135 76.474 362.535-89.989 362.535-89.989s192.293-170.125 342.736 34.358C911.755 386.145 71.696 401.14 71.696 401.14l-387.603-81.536 37.428-93.982z'
            opacity='0.2'
          ></path>
        </g>
        <path
          fill='url(#paint5_linear)'
          fillRule='evenodd'
          d='M97 228c11.046 0 20-4.477 20-10s-8.954-10-20-10-20 4.477-20 10 8.954 10 20 10z'
          clipRule='evenodd'
        ></path>
        <path
          fill='url(#paint6_linear)'
          fillRule='evenodd'
          d='M99.137 149.056c5.942-3.428 8.257-10.538 5.169-15.881s-10.409-6.896-16.352-3.469c-5.942 3.428-8.257 10.538-5.169 15.882 3.088 5.343 10.409 6.896 16.352 3.468z'
          clipRule='evenodd'
        ></path>
        <path
          fill='url(#paint7_linear)'
          fillRule='evenodd'
          d='M232.229 136.879c-2.082-2.662-5.714-3.302-8.113-1.43-2.398 1.872-2.655 5.547-.573 8.21 2.082 2.662 5.714 3.303 8.113 1.431 2.398-1.872 2.655-5.548.573-8.211z'
          clipRule='evenodd'
        ></path>
      </g>
      <defs>
        <filter
          id='filter0_d'
          width='315'
          height='315'
          x='0'
          y='0'
          colorInterpolationFilters='sRGB'
          filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <feFlood floodOpacity='0' result='BackgroundImageFix'></feFlood>
          <feColorMatrix
            in='SourceAlpha'
            values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0'
          ></feColorMatrix>
          <feOffset dy='20'></feOffset>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='25'></feGaussianBlur>
          <feColorMatrix values='0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0.431373 0 0 0 0 0.815686 0 0 0 0.4 0'></feColorMatrix>
          <feBlend
            in2='BackgroundImageFix'
            result='effect1_dropShadow'
          ></feBlend>
          <feBlend
            in='SourceGraphic'
            in2='effect1_dropShadow'
            result='shape'
          ></feBlend>
        </filter>
        <linearGradient
          id='paint0_linear'
          x1='52.551'
          x2='116.063'
          y1='105.43'
          y2='220.489'
          gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <stop stopColor='#AEFF98'></stop>
          <stop offset='1' stopColor='#FFBC4C'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id='paint1_linear'
          x1='-388.819'
          x2='-336.97'
          y1='49.634'
          y2='410.633'
          gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <stop stopColor='#FFDFA9'></stop>
          <stop offset='1' stopColor='#FF54EC'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id='paint2_linear'
          x1='105.815'
          x2='61.156'
          y1='66.613'
          y2='213.114'
          gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <stop stopColor='#FF4DB3'></stop>
          <stop offset='1' stopColor='#FF78D9'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id='paint3_linear'
          x1='142.941'
          x2='146.348'
          y1='47.303'
          y2='256.385'
          gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <stop stopColor='#FF91CE'></stop>
          <stop offset='1' stopColor='#9650FF'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id='paint4_linear'
          x1='90.806'
          x2='118.772'
          y1='-12.145'
          y2='130.147'
          gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <stop stopColor='#73E9FF'></stop>
          <stop offset='1' stopColor='#5888FF'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id='paint5_linear'
          x1='101.92'
          x2='86.91'
          y1='214.248'
          y2='214.248'
          gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <stop stopColor='#B261F2'></stop>
          <stop offset='1' stopColor='#FF77D9'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id='paint6_linear'
          x1='94.095'
          x2='86.022'
          y1='134.222'
          y2='138.883'
          gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <stop stopColor='#FCBB5F'></stop>
          <stop offset='1' stopColor='#FF9EC9'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id='paint7_linear'
          x1='225.33'
          x2='228.158'
          y1='140.355'
          y2='143.975'
          gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
        >
          <stop stopColor='#FCA45F'></stop>
          <stop offset='1' stopColor='#C76EE8'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  )
}

export default Bg
```

**And here is the page where I'm importing the file to**

```
import React from 'react'
import Bg from './../svg/Bg'

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div className='container video'>
      <div className='inner-container'>
        <div className='video__grid'>
          <div className='video__col video__col--text'>
            <h2 className='video__title'>Workflow that just works</h2>
            <p className='video__text'>
              Collaboration should be simple, straightforward, and effective.
              With Pitch, it is. Discuss current activities, manage tasks, and
              stay productive as a team. Create on any device, online or
              offline, and get great work done faster.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className='video__col'>
            <Bg/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

**Thanks!!!!**

Comment: Do you have more than one element on the page with the same id value?

Comment: You should provide a producible example as this is "not react's fault" and has something to do with other styles in your application. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What react are you using? Did you compare the SVG output that is produced by React?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will check the id issue. I didn't check it before.
I'm using react 16.13.11

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a class name problem... Usually when exporting svg from another software it is exported with a default name for each vector element.
Maybe you are looking for this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039230/15142235